# Inconsistent error using HQ camera

Tags: python, pi-4, camera, libcamera

I have been having some issues using the HQ pi camera. I am running Rasbian 11, latest apt update 11 march 2022. I use libcamera-still to take images and I call this command using python subprocess.Open.

The problem I am encountering is an inconsistent one, that seems to pop up randomly over time. To give a bit of background, I have a machine that takes images every 5 seconds, about 300-400 per day.

Most of the time this runs fine, but sometimes I get the following error:

```
Preview windows only support YUV420.
```

This seems to then freeze the image taking, as no image file is being written to my disk.

Rebooting the machine fixes the issue.

How would I approach trouble-shooting this issue?

Answer (score 0):

for your vnc question: (iam not allowed to answer because of my reputation points wtf)

sudo nano /boot/config.txt

uncomment:

hdmi_froce_hotplug, hdmi_group, hdmi_mode

to force a resolution for vnc

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).